# 100k "thank yous" or 100k "thank you's"?

Tags: word-choice

I wanted to thank people for their visits to a profile but Google wasn't quite sure either. Is there another way to express the same meaning?

Comment: What about 'a thousand thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the expresion comes from a verbal form, so the noun has to be hyphenated. 
So, it is one "thank-you" or several "thank-you's" (because of the compound form).

but, in everyday use, "thank yous" is also correct. and please note that hyphens are also omitted in everyday use so it might become "thank you's".

you can also say " I thank you all for ..." or " I express my gratitude to all..." or " I am thankful..."

Comment: I'd be tempted to use _thank-you_'s with the apostrophe, and perhaps the italicisation, as one could claim it's a use of a 'word as a word' (as in 'There are too many _but_'s in this sentence'). One could also argue that yous looks outlandish and requires the style-apostrophe (as some allow for ex's and do's). _Grammar Girl_ likes the hyphen for the nounal usage, but not the apostrophe. Have you any authority to back up your choice?

Comment: I suggested this answer just out of my awareness. however, I'll look for some evidence. although we all do speak "all the but's" and "all the do's and don't's", it would seem appropriate to do the same with "thank you".

Comment: No; not everyone writes (which is what we're addressing here)  "all the do's and don't's". Some people omit the apostrophes before the s in each case. Then again, almost all people begin sentences and most sentence-substitutes with capital letters, and it's normal practice here.

Comment: well, then it should be up to the user's discretion, shouldn't it. that is because both the styles get the message conveyed and the right-wrong issue cannot be addressed because both these styles have gone deep and have been widely accepted.

Comment: Are you saying that 'So, it is one "thank-you" or several "thank-you's" (because of the compound form).' wasn't quite right, then?

Comment: I stated the opinion because it is also considered right, not because it is the only right thing. :-) and I am confused about what are we talking about. I am getting off the subject I think. do you say it's wrong?

Comment: It is one "thank-you" and several "thank-yous" or several "thank-you's". OP **is** asking about whether the **apostrophe** is correct.

Comment: The apostrophe should be reserved for the saxon genitive. There is no valid reason why anyone should write "thank you's". That's just bad grammar. If it's the plural you want to denote, then clearly just put an 's' at the end, as is normal practise.